# Create Trigger after insert copy vaule from column A to column B

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-trigger

I am try to create a trigger in SQL server to automatically copy a value to another column from inserted row.

I have application which insert records to table KNT. After inserted I need copy Value from column GID to column ID

Now I Have

```
GID | ID 
1   | null
2   | null
3   | null
```

What I want

```
GID | ID 
1   | 1
2   | 2
3   | 3
```

What I tried:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER GIDONID
       ON  dbo.KNT
       AFTER INSERT
    AS 

    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @GIDTOCOPY as INT
    SET @GIDTOCOPY=(select top 1 GID from inserted)
        UPDATE dbo.KNT SET ID=@GIDTOCOPY WHERE GID=@GIDTOCOPY 

END
```

Comment: The only error I see here is the name of the variable. What error do you see?

Comment: Sorry. To fast fingers - I just  corrected this - but that's not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is trigger code that *would work*. Join `inserted` to the table and do a set based update instead of trying to do row by row updates (which is never good in a trigger because it will fail any time you insert more than 1 row):

```
UPDATE k
SET k.ID = i.GID
FROM inserted i
JOIN KNT k on i.GID = k.GID
```

However I'd really, really recommend just inserting the value into both columns from your application if you need to do this.  It's pretty suspect why you need the same data duplicated in another field to begin with, but letting the application do it adds practically no work and a trigger adds a whole extra process.